# Uninstall Java Mac OS X

Tags: java, macos

I am trying to remove JDK and JRE from my mac to revert back to an older version. I tried removing jdk folder from System/Library/Java/VirtualMachines as described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/mac/mac-jre.html#uninstall) and i al so removed the Java applet as described [here](http://java.com/en/download/help/mac_uninstall_java.xml) but i can still see java installed on my mac. Typing `java -version` gives me the following output:

```
        Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_71-b14)
        Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.71-b01, mixed mode)
```

Typing `ls -l /usr/bin/java` gives the following output -

```
/usr/bin/java -> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java
```

I can see a lot of folders at this location and i don't really know which one to delete to uninstall Java completely and install an older version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Java 7 JDK is under `/Library`, not `/System/Library`.

Only Apple software is allowed to use `/System`, Java 7 and later are supplied by Oracle, so install under `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines`. Deleting the appropriate JDK directory from there should be enough to complete the un-installation. In particular you should *not* touch anything under `/System/Library/Frameworks`, the stuff in there is either for backwards compatibility with apps that expect the old Apple Java installation paths from Java 5 and earlier, or for the stub mechanism that makes `/usr/bin/java` work (and delegate to whichever real JDK is the current target of `JAVA_HOME`).

Comment: Thanks. I figured that out. but i have already deleted the System JDK. Can i restore it ?

Comment: @sayed if it's just the `/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines` one you mean (i.e. the Apple Java 6 JDK) then you should be able to re-install that from the latest ["Java for OS X" package from apple](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572)

Comment: For reference, find the official guide to uninstalling Java for Mac OSX on the Oracle Website.

**Java 7**: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/mac/mac-jdk.html#uninstall
**Java 8**: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/mac_jdk.html#A1096903